# Would psutil.cpu_percentage depict a true CPU usage of a docker container running in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to monitor CPU percentage usage of a Docker container and get alerted when it reaches a certain threshold.

My application is running in a Docker container, that is running in a Kubernetes pod.

What should be my concern `- monitor` the CPU usage of the pod, right?

The incident was not being able to connect to the application because the CPU was swamped, and the deduction of the CPU being swamped was made by entering and topping the container.

Answer (score 0):

The `psuitl.Process.cpu_percent` calculates the unix-style utilization, this style sums the per-core utilization so you can use it to check your cpu utilization.

Also, you can use `docker stats` [command](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/) to live stream a container’s runtime metrics, and there is a graphical tool  [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) (Container Advisor)  that could help you to  understand  the resource usage and performance on your containers.

You can find a guide on how to deploy Prometheus and cAdvisor  in this [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/cadvisor/#monitoring-docker-container-metrics-using-cadvisor) . There are other tools like [scout](https://scoutapm.com/) that also helps to get alerts, but you will need to pay to use it